# React в return надо вывести <tr></tr><tr></tr>

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Допустим имеем следующий код

```
render(){
return(
<table>
<tbody>
   {this.state.jornal.map((item) =>{
       return(
         <tr><td>{item.name}</td><td>{item.description}</td></tr>
         <tr><td>{item.name2}</td><td>{item.description2}</td></tr>
      );
})}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Как выкрутиться из такой ситуации? return в React не может выводить два тега. А завернуть 2-a `<tr>` не во что, вся таблица летит к чертям

Comment: Можно использовать несколько <tbody>.

Comment: Сергей боженька)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте React.Fragment

```
return(
<React.Fragment>
<tr><td>{item.name}</td><td>{item.description}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{item.name2}</td><td>{item.description2}</td></tr>
</React.Fragment>
)
```

Также можно использовать короткий короткий синтаксис - пустые теги, но он не всегда всегда поддерживается и в нем не используются ключи и атрибуты.

```
return(
<>
<tr><td>{item.name}</td><td>{item.description}</td></tr>
<tr><td>{item.name2}</td><td>{item.description2}</td></tr>
</>
)
```

Дополнительно об этом можно почитать здесь:

1. https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-react-91d6dd5070b0
2. https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactfragment
3. https://learn-reactjs.ru/core/fragments#short-syntax